# Excel: Create dynamic ranges from a portion of Data table to be used for Pivot Table

Tags: excel, dynamic, range

I was wondering if you could help me with the following need:
I have data table in excel, the data contains information of two years.
What I want to do is to create 2 sets of dynamic ranges (1 for each year) to be used on pivot tables.
Here below I have put an example of my starting data, which requires to be split in 2 (2018 and 2019).
The result I am trying to achieve is: One dynamic range of A1:E6, and another of A7:e12 +headings.
Is there a way to achieve it?
Thank you in advance,

[image]

Comment: You can create two pivot tables of the entire data then use a filter on the pivot tables to only include the correct year in each.

Comment: I know but I would rather skip this option since it is not as efficient as using dynamic ranges

Comment: The only other way I know of is to use two helper tables that have the data filtered and the two pivot tables then refer to them.